# Quote area including a left bar

Tags: tcolorbox, examples

Finally, I managed to create a own quote style with that:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

\newtcolorbox{zitat}{
    colback=block-gray,
    grow to right by=-10mm,
    grow to left by=-10mm, 
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    breakable
}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{aquote}[1]
  {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{zitat}}
  {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{zitat}}
```

[image]

But i looking forward using a new style.
I like to have a quote style that has a gray bar on th left site and the quote area should be angular shaped. The area should include he source like in my approach above as well.
[image]

Does anyone of you have an approach? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `examples`? It's clearly a `tcolorbox` - related question. And please add the working document, not just fragments

Answer (score 10):

I've used the original `zitat` `tcolorbox` environment and extended it  a little bit, detaching a title to the upper box, with bold font, and `\large` as fontsize declaration.

The vertical line can be generated with the `borderline west=...` option, the box is breakable,as is shown in the screenshot.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} 
\definecolor{block-gray}{gray}{0.95}


\newtcolorbox{zitat}[2][]{%
    colback=block-gray,
    grow to right by=-10mm,
    grow to left by=-10mm, 
    boxrule=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    breakable,
    enhanced jigsaw,
    borderline west={4pt}{0pt}{gray},
    title={#2\par},
    colbacktitle={block-gray},
    coltitle={black},
    fonttitle={\large\bfseries},
    attach title to upper={},
    #1,
}



\begin{document}
\begin{zitat}{Minimal working document}
A document that contains the relevant documentclass, the packages, a document-environment and the code that produces the issue.

\blindtext[5] 
\end{zitat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I realized such a box a few times ago with TikZ, and here was the (not really well designed) code used.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

%% Global libraries
\usepackage[textwidth=18cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm]{geometry}

%% Libraries for graphics and colours
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox} 

\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{195,195,195}

\newcommand\todoFrame[2]{\vspace{.3cm}\noindent\tikz{
\node (contentnode) [draw, color = #1!25, fill=#1!15, text=black, rectangle, outer sep = 0, rounded corners = 1mm, minimum width=\linewidth-1, text width=\linewidth, align=justify, below right] at (0,0) {\noindent #2};
\draw[fill opacity = 1, color=#1, fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle ([xshift=5]contentnode.south west);}
\par}

\newcommand\todoEnv[3]{\par\todoFrame{#1}{\noindent\hspace*{.3cm}\textbf{\textcolor{#1}{\Large{#2}}}\vspace*{.2cm}\newline\noindent\hspace*{.3cm}\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-.3cm\relax}#3\end{minipage}}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}
\todoEnv{mygray}{Fragment}{A \textbf{fragment} is a piece of an activity whice enable more modular activity design. It will not be wrong if we say, a fragment is a kind of \textbf{sub-activity}.}

\end{document}
```

Please note that this solution will not break at page break...

[image]

Although, as suggested in the comments, `tcolorbox` seems more appropriate here (if anyone want to submit a response with it, feel free to do so!).

In any case, I hope it may help you.

Comment: It could be possible with `borderline` settings, as far as I know, that would be breakable!